# Yeoman Angular not working with ngRoutes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, angularjs-routing

I just created a new Yeoman angular project. The basic site worked when I started grunt serve.  I tried to modify the project to use ngRoute so I could add more views, but I can't get any of the views to actually show up.  This is what I have:

**index.html:**

```
...
<div ng-view></div>
...
```

**app.js:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
   'ngRoute',
   'ngCookies',
   'ui.bootstrap'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
     .when('/', { templateUrl: '/views/main.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'})
     .when('/view2', { templateUrl: '/views/view2.html', controller: 'View2Ctrl'})
     .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

view2.html has some text inside of it, and main.html is still the default page that came with the project.  Any thoughts on what I did wrong.  Let me know if you need to see other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is, but it has to do with my version of angular.js which is AngularJS v1.2.6.  Instead I used AngularJSv1.1.5 which is working.  If someone can tell me what changed between the two and what I need to do to modify, that would still be appreciated!

Comment: Haven't been using Yeoman, but the main difference between the two that I could think of that would affect this is that the routing was moved out to it's own module as of 1.2.

In your app code you correctly include "ngRoute", is the "angular-route.min.js" loaded as well?

Answer (score 0):

if you view the JavaScript console, does it show any errors? Everything shown seems fine, but there may be an error with the controller, or the controller maybe wasn't loaded? Be sure to add the View2controller.js to your index file.

---

additionally, this is taken from another post:

```
    http://localhost:9000/#/view2
```

(supposing you are running the site from your local machine)